# How to detect if a .txt file is used by another process and terminate it?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian.
I am working on a program that gets the room temp. and humidity with a sensor.
Now I am trying to log those values in a .txt file.
I figured out how to do that but i want to check if the file is used by any other process (a texteditor for example) and terminate  that process before I log the values in the .txt file.

So how do I figure out if the .txt file is used by any other process and how do I terminate that process.

I know that I can open/close an editable instance of the file in the background with:

```
File = open(„Path“,“editmode“)

DoSomething()

File.close()
```

But thats not the functionality that I need.

Comment: Which OS runs on the Raspberry Pi 3? You might need to check the process iisting/resources which are open..

Comment: I am using Raspbian. How can I check these listing/resources?